# Count ignoring duplicate documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'd like to count all emails within the specific project (ID: 7), but ignoring duplicate rows in ONE campaign.

Here's the example of my collection structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581a9054c274f7b512e8ed94"),
    "email" : "a@example.com",
    "IDproject" : 7,
    "IDcampaign" : 10
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581a9064c274f7b512e8ed95"),
    "email" : "b@example.com",
    "IDproject" : 7,
    "IDcampaign" : 10
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581a9068c274f7b512e8ed96"),
    "email" : "b@example.com",
    "IDproject" : 7,
    "IDcampaign" : 10
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581a906cc274f7b512e8ed97"),
    "email" : "b@example.com",
    "IDproject" : 7,
    "IDcampaign" : 11
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581a9072c274f7b512e8ed98"),
    "email" : "c@example.com",
    "IDproject" : 7,
    "IDcampaign" : 11
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581a9079c274f7b512e8ed99"),
    "email" : "d@example.com",
    "IDproject" : 7,
    "IDcampaign" : 12
}
```

This is what the result should be:

```
a@example.com 
b@example.com 
b@example.com 
c@example.com 
d@example.com
```

`Total: 5` (of 6). Note that `b@example.com` is mentioned twice. That's because `b@example.com` has campaigns 10, 10 and 11. We're ignoring one 10.

This is what I've tried:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {$match : {IDproject : 7}},
    {$group : {_id : "$email", total : {$sum : 1}}}
])
```

But it returns only unique emails ignoring `IDcampaign`. Also, I can get unique number of emails with the following query:

```
db.mycollection.distinct('email', {IDproject : 7})
```

But again, it shows only unique emails ignoring `IDcampaign`.

Could someone give me a hint how to count emails including `IDcampaign`?

Thanks.

p.s. I use MongoDB with PHP, and I can solve the problem with PHP calculations, but that's not the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include it as part of your group key, as in the following example:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "IDproject": 7 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "email" : "$email",                
                "IDcampaign" : "$IDcampaign"
            },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "email" : "a@example.com",
        "IDcampaign" : 10
    },
    "count" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "email" : "d@example.com",
        "IDcampaign" : 12
    },
    "count" : 1
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "email" : "b@example.com",
        "IDcampaign" : 11
    },
    "count" : 1
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "email" : "b@example.com",
        "IDcampaign" : 10
    },
    "count" : 2
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "email" : "c@example.com",
        "IDcampaign" : 11
    },
    "count" : 1
}
```

---

To answer your follow-up question on getting the count only since you don't need the list of emails, you could run the following pipeline

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "IDproject": 7 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "count": { "$sum": 1 },
            "emails": {
                "$addToSet": {
                    "email" : "$email",                
                    "IDcampaign" : "$IDcampaign"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "count": 1,
            "total": { "$size": "$emails" }
        }
    }
])
```

which gives you the result

```
{        
    "total" : 5,
    "count" : 6
}
```

that you can interpret as `Total 5 (of 6)`

Comment: Yep and then you can use the $project stage to reshape your output.

For example: {$project: { email: "$_id.email", IDcampaign: "$_id.IDcampaign", total: "$total", _id: 0 } }

Comment: @dyouberg do not add `$project` just to reshape the document here. It is not necessary and will cause a drop of performance.

Comment: @chridam I was so close! This is great. Thanks.

Comment: @dyouberg thanks. I'm wondering if there's a way to get a number since I don't need the list of emails - only the number.

Comment: Add another $group to count your results:

{ $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }

Comment: @Nedim Added a followup answer for you.